# Current date should add 12 hours more in android

Tags: android

In my application i want to add 12 hours with the current date and time,then i have to show it in this format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss". I wrote the code but unable to add 12 hours. How can i do? please help.

My code is :

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            Date date = cal.getTime();
            String date1 = (new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")).format(date);
            m_tvTrackEnd.setText(date1);
```

Answer (score 6):

The `Calendar` class has the `add` method which you can use to add certain units.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, 12);
Date date = cal.getTime();
String date1 = (new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")).format(date);
m_tvTrackEnd.setText(date1);
```

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();    
        Date date = cal.getTime()+12*60*60*1000;
        String date1 = (new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")).format(date);
        m_tvTrackEnd.setText(date1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add the 12 hours to the Calendar object like this:

```
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, 12)
        Date date = cal.getTime();
        String date1 = (new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")).format(date);
        m_tvTrackEnd.setText(date1);
```